# Call Method from Linq query

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am using Linq query and call method Like..

```
oPwd = objDecryptor.DecryptIt((c.Password.ToString())
```

it will return null value.

Means this will not working.

how I Resolve this.

Thanks..

```
var q =
    from s in db.User
    join c in db.EmailAccount on s.UserId equals c.UserId
    join d in db.POPSettings 
        on c.PopSettingId equals d.POPSettingsId
    where s.UserId == UserId && c.EmailId == EmailId
    select new
    {
        oUserId = s.UserId,
        oUserName = s.Name,
        oEmailId = c.EmailId,
        oEmailAccId = c.EmailAccId,
        oPwd = objDecryptor.DecryptIt(c.Password.ToString()),
        oServerName = d.ServerName,
        oServerAdd = d.ServerAddress,
        oPOPSettingId = d.POPSettingsId,
    };
```

Comment: BTW, best-practice is simply not to store passwords. Not even encrypted. Just hashed with salt. Oh, and those property names are *horrible*.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside DecryptIt(...) and figure out why it's returning null?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If that is LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework. You'll need to break it into steps (as it can't execute that at the DB). For example:

```
var q = from s in db.User
        join c in db.EmailAccount on s.UserId equals c.UserId
        join d in db.POPSettings on c.PopSettingId equals d.POPSettingsId
        where s.UserId == UserId && c.EmailId == EmailId
        select new
        {
            oUserId = s.UserId,
            oUserName = s.Name,
            oEmailId = c.EmailId,
            oEmailAccId = c.EmailAccId,
            oPwd = c.Password,
            oServerName = d.ServerName,
            oServerAdd = d.ServerAddress,
            oPOPSettingId = d.POPSettingsId,
        };
```

then use `AsEnumerable()` to break "composition" against the back-end store:

```
var query2 = from row in q.AsEnumerable()
        select new
        {
            row.oUserId,
            row.oUserName,
            row.oEmailId,
            row.oEmailAccId,
            oPwd = objDecryptor.DecryptIt(row.oPwd),
            row.oServerName,
            row.oServerAdd,
            row.oPOPSettingId
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = from s in db.User
    join c in db.EmailAccount on s.UserId equals c.UserId
    join d in db.POPSettings on c.PopSettingId equals d.POPSettingsId
    where s.UserId == UserId && c.EmailId == EmailId
    select new
    {
        oUserId = s.UserId,
        oUserName = s.Name,
        oEmailId = c.EmailId,
        oEmailAccId = c.EmailAccId,
        oPwd = c.Password,
        oServerName = d.ServerName,
        oServerAdd = d.ServerAddress,
        oPOPSettingId = d.POPSettingsId,
    };

foreach (var item in q)
        {
            item.oPwd = objDecryptor.DecryptIt(row.oPwd),
        }
```

we can use a foreach loop also to update a single property. do not need to select all property in next query.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing about Linq query. you need to debug method `objDecryptor.DecryptIt`

Comment: You can add breakpoint to DecryptIt method and you'll see why it returns null.

Comment: When I am debuging at that time it direct pass to this query so
how I Comes to Know ..
But the objDecryptor.DecryptIt it's working properly.

Comment: @Jitendra Jadav please, try to concentrate and ask question from beginning to end as clear as possible. Please try to use English better. i am really lost.