# use external function in LINQ

Tags: linq, function

is it possible to use external function in linq select resault ?
and how to pass param to it?

```
sub x
Dim q = From a In contex Select New With {.z=z("MYNAME")}
end sub

function z(name as string)
return( name & "Something...")
end function
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the choosen provider. With `normal` LINQ over `IEnumerable` queries (a.k.a. LINQ to Objects) you can do. However, with most LINQ over Expression trees (such as LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, NHibernate, LLBLGen, etc, etc) you can't. Those providers convert an expression tree to some other language, such as SQL, AD, SharePoint, etc, etc. They just don't know what to do with your custom method.

You can solve this in several ways. For instance, try to write the code of the method inline in the query. This way the provider knows what to do with it. Another option is to let the method call outside of the expression tree. For instance (sorry my C#):

```
var q = (from a in context select a).AsEnumerable();

// q is an IEnumerable and the z method will be called by .NET instead
// of being translated to SQL.
var q2 = (from a in q select new { z = z("MYNAME") };
```

Answer (score 0):

That has been answered and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772939/call-method-from-linq-query) at StackOverflow. Please have a look.
And the complete explanation of what you are trying to do can be found [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx).