# Dynamically Modifying Where Condition in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, predicate

The following Entity Framework query runs without error.

```
Predicate<Program> filterProgram;
if (programId.HasValue)
    filterProgram = (p => p.Id == programId && !p.IsDeleted);
else
    filterProgram = (p => !p.IsDeleted);

var analytics = (from a in repository.Query<Analytic>()
                 where (a.Marker == "Open" || a.Marker == "LastTouch") &&
                 a.EntityType == "Proposal" &&
                 a.Site == "C"
                 join p in repository.Query<Program>()
                 on a.EntityId equals p.Id
                 //where filterProgram(p)
                 group a
                 by new { a.LoginSessionId, a.EntityId, p.Id, p.Name } into g
                 let f = g.OrderBy(x => x.TimestampUtc).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Marker == "Open")
                 where f != null
                 let t = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Marker == "LastTouch" && x.TimestampUtc > f.TimestampUtc)
                 select new
                 {
                     ProgramId = g.Key.Id,
                     Program = g.Key.Name,
                     ProposalId = g.Key.EntityId,
                     FirstOpen = f,
                     LastTouch = (t ?? f).TimestampUtc
                 }).ToList();
```

However, if I uncomment the line `where filterProgram(p)`, I get the run-time error:

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

I was expecting that LINQ would be able to incorporate my predicate into the query and convert it to SQL. Why am I getting this error, and is there a way to dynamically modify a where predicate this way?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but can you try to define filterProgram as `Expression<Predicate<Program>>` instead?

Comment: Well, that gives me a compile error on where the predicate is called  "'filterProgram' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `filterProgram`'s type to `Expression<Func<Program, bool>>` and then it should be usable in a LINQ Where clause.

One caveat, however: I managed to get it to work in method chain syntax, but not in query syntax.

For example, this works:

```
dataContext.Programs.Where (filterProgram)
```

but this does not:

```
from p in dataContext.Programs
where filterprogram
```

*(The compiler complains that it cannot resolve method `Where`, which is available on both `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`.)*

In your case, it might be acceptable to replace the line

```
join p in repository.Query<Program>()
```

with

```
join p in repository.Query<Program>().Where(filterProgram)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused because Entity Framework needs to be able to convert your LINQ query into SQL. Your LINQ query is compiled into a data structure called an Expression tree which is then passed to Entity Framework for conversion to SQL.

You have two options:

1. Replace your call to `filterProgram` with a more basic C# expression. Depending on the complexity of `filterProgram` this may not be possible.
2. Remove you call to `filterProgram`, and convert this query to an `IEnumerable<T>`, maybe by calling `.ToList()`. You can then further filter the results of this query using `filterProgram`

**Example of 2**

```
   var query = /* Your Query With filterProgram commented out */
   var resultsFromSql = query.ToList();
   var fullyFiltered = resultsFromSql.Select(filterProgram);
```

Comment: I don't think the second option is a good one as it will pull all the unfiltered rows from the database. But perhaps I can modify the query to do the tests needed for all versions of `filterProgram`.

Comment: @JonathanWood It really depends on how many rows are returned by the query without `filterProgram`. As you've said it may be possible to use  both options by moving some of the functionality of `filterProgram` into the query and doing the rest after fetching the result.

Answer (score 1):

In Linq to Entities it is not possible to call an external method without converting the query to `IEnumerable`. Thus, since `filterProgram` is a method, you may not call inside the query.

If possible you may call `ToList` before calling the `FilterProgram` and it will work.
Another option maybe inserting the logic of `filterProgram` into the query.

Comment: Calling `ToList()` before the filter would be horribly inefficient because it would bring all the filtered items from the database. Inserting the logic into the query is what I want to do, but how to do it dynamically?

Comment: @JonathanWood you are absolutely right, but I see no options here. you may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772939/call-method-from-linq-query

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that linq2entities tries to translate the expression tree to SQL your expression tree has an invocation of the method `Invoke` on a delegate type (filterProgram)
however there's nothing stopping you from inlining that predicate

```
var id= programId.HasValue ? programId.GetValueOrDefault() : -1;
var analytics = (from a in repository.Query<Analytic>()
                 where (a.Marker == "Open" || a.Marker == "LastTouch") &&
                 a.EntityType == "Proposal" &&
                 a.Site == "C"
                 join p in repository.Query<Program>()
                 on a.EntityId equals p.Id
                 where !p.IsDeleted && (!hasValue || p.Id == id)
                 ....
```

This assumes that -1 is an invalid programId